# what's << in ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code that use in a rails model:

```
self.groups << Group.find_by_name("User")
```

what's this << ?
Is there any document about it?

Comment: First look at the *type* of `self.groups`. Then go find the documentation for that type. For instance, if `self.groups` is an Array, then see [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C). Since operators in Ruby are *just methods*, this search strategy will work for any type/operator pairing.

Comment: Essentially its a method that means to append a something to a something.  In ruby, you can append item to an array, an object to a collection of object, append methods to class instance.  You can search for << here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get it wrong. In the case of OP's question, `<<` is **not** a method of `Array`. Instead, it's a method of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`.

Source code here

```
  def <<(*records)
    proxy_association.concat(records) && self
  end
  alias_method :push, :<<
  alias_method :append, :<<
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b15ce4a006756a0b6cacfb9593d88c9a7dfd8eb0/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L944 (Code is for Rails 4, and in Rails 3 it works the same)

This method is for object which has_many other objects. The collection of other objects can use this method to add new associated object, **association id assigned automatically** and the new object **got saved to db**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

question = Question.last # id: 100
question.answers.size # 0
question.answers << Answer.new(body: 'demo answer')

question.answers.size # 1

Answer.last # id: 1, question_id: 100, body: 'demo answer'
# Note here, the contacted answer got saved in db.
```

You can also use the aliased methods which works the same:

```
question.answers.push Answer.new(body: 'demo answer')
question.answers.append Answer.new(body: 'demo answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

With this method you can push an element into an array if `self.groups` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is the Ruby 'append' operator which is defined for the base classes Array and String to concatenate objects to any Array or String (in case of strings the `.to_s` method must be defined on the object).

Any Ruby operator can be overloaded in Ruby. And any of the Ruby operators can be also used in any custom class, just like any other named method.

In Rails ActiveRecord::Associations the `<<` operator is defined to append records to an association. (see reference at the bottom)

In your particular example, the `<<` operator appends the found records to the 'groups' association. If no record was found, then nothing is appended.

Here's an example on how to overload (or define) `<<` in a class:

```
  class Array
    def <<(arg)
      puts arg.inspect
    end
  end

  [] << 'something awful'
  => 'something awful'
```

See also:

[Ruby Array `<<` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)

[Ruby String `<<` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)

[Rails ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods `<<` operator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)